# How to combine two update queries having different set and where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to optimize database access by combining this two queries, if possible.

How to combine this two statements into one?

```
update tbl_priority SET a=1 where j='j1' and priority='1';
update tbl_priority SET g=1 where j='j1';
```

Any help, suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you ALWAYS updating G and sometimes updating A? I'm trying to figure out the value of doing this in one step over two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a nice clean way of combining these two update statements, because the logic in the `WHERE` clause does not agree.  However, we can retain the common condition `j = 'j1'` in the `WHERE` clause, and then use a `CASE` expression to handle the `a` assignement:

```
UPDATE tbl_priority
SET a = CASE WHEN priority = '1' THEN 1 ELSE a END,
    g = 1
WHERE j = 'j1'
```

Note that this is not ideal because we have a branch of the `CASE` expression which assigns `a` back to itself.  This by itself should not cause a particular record to show up as having been modified though.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
update tbl_priority SET g=1, a = CASE WHEN priority='1' THEN 1 ELSE a END 
where j='j1' ;
```